# I need to solve the general equation for the union of the elements of a set to calculate propabilitys of the set in python

Tags: python, list, set, union, probability

In math language:

```
list=[1,3,4]
Solve=1+3+4-1*3-1*4-3*4-1*3*4
```

The general function:

```
A1∪A2∪..∪An= A1+A2+..+An-A1*A2-A1...-A1*A2*...*An
```

I need to create a function to solve this problem for any number of objects in a list.

The slow way:

a=[2,2,1]

b=(a[0]|a[1]|a[2])

I need the general solution!

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm following your pattern, you can generate all the combinations of size 2..N using `itertools.combinations` then for each combination you can multiple the tuple using `functools.reduce` with the `operator.mul` operation. Then negate these values within `sum`.

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import mul

>>> data = [1,3,4]
>>> sum(data) + sum(sum(-reduce(mul, i) for i in combinations(data, n)) for n in range(2, len(data)+1))
-23
```

Comment: Thank you! Yo have a lot a of experiencie and you share it!